# Ruby Memcached maninuplating stored data

Tags: ruby, memcached

I am storing an array in `memcached` (see below)

```
Cache.set 'an_array', [1,2,3,4,5.....N]
```

I need to pop one value from the array and update the array in Cache again

```
arr = Cache.get 'an_array'
val = arr.pop
Cache.set 'an_array', arr
```

Is there a direct way I can pop the value from array stored in Cache and the array get updated automatically? Actually the array to be stored is very huge and it will be very costly to first fetch the array, pop the value and then do a `Cache.set` with updated array.

Thanks,

Imran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is an in-built version of pop command available in memcached. According to the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands) only these commands available

```
      o Standard Protocol
            + No Reply
      o Storage Commands
            + set
            + add
            + replace
            + append
            + prepend
            + cas
      o Retrieval Commands
            + get
            + gets
      o delete
      o incr/decr
      o Statistics
            + stats
            + stats items
            + stats slabs
            + stats sizes
      o flush_all
```

**Update:**

If you are starting and looking for other options. i would highly recommend redis for your case. It provides higher set of commands over memcached.

For example, you can pop the value from redis array in multiple ways.

- [LPOP](http://redis.io/commands/lpop)
- [RPOP](http://redis.io/commands/rpop)
- [BLPOP](http://redis.io/commands/blpop)
- [BRPOP](http://redis.io/commands/brpop)
- [SPOP](http://redis.io/commands/spop)

Check out the whole set of [redis command](http://redis.io/commands)s here.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. By the way, is it possible to implement such a function for our custom use?

Comment: I dont have any expeience in Memcached internal. But sure you can, since the source is available open...